# How to compile GCC cross-compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, gmp, mpfr, mpc

I am trying to compile GCC for i586-elf but every time I run the 'configure' file with this command:

```
./configure --target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX --disable-nls --enable
languages=c --without-headers --with-gmp=$PREFIX --with-mpc=$PREFIX
--with-mpfr=$PREFIX
```

Then it gives me this error:

```
checking for the correct version of gmp.h... yes
checking for the correct version of mpfr.h... yes
checking for the correct version of mpc.h... yes
checking for the correct version of the gmp/mpfr/mpc libraries... no.
```

Although I have specified where gmp, mpfr, and mpc are located. And I have the latest versions of them. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Stop shouting PLEASE and write a title that is more meaningful. It's clear you *need help*, or you wouldn't be posting here, and screaming *PLEASE* is a little demanding and rude when you're asking people to **donate their time** to **help you for free**. The error message tells you what's wrong - it's not finding the **specific version** that it requires. *Latest* doesn't mean *correct*.

Comment: How can someone answer this question  without knowing '$TARGET' , '$PREFIX' . ?  There might be some lines in log which says the package version needed and version it found on your PC.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you *really* care about specific gmp/mpfr etc versions I suggest you run the `contrib/download_prerequisites` script from the top-level GCC source directory and then omit the `--with-gmp=$PREFIX --with-mpc=$PREFIX --with-mpfr=$PREFIX` from your configure line. The `download_prerequisites` script will download and unpack the right versions of the libraries that your GCC version needs and it will create the right symlinks in the right places

Comment: Thanks that helped!